# blocks in a raw in html page with different width

Tags: html, css

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/LDnfQ/) which has three blocks of equal width. How can we make this of different sizes, say given 100%, first block 20%, second block 50% and the third 30%.

```
<div class="Row">
    <div class="Column">C1</div>
    <div class="Column">C2</div>
    <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div><div class="Row">
    <div class="Column">C1</div>
    <div class="Column">C2</div>
    <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>


.Row
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}
.Column
{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `nth-child`:

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: red;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column">C1</div>
  <div class="Column">C2</div>
  <div class="Column">C3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need the red background color of each cell partially changed say the first cell 100% second cell 100% and the third cell 50%, how can that be achieved?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Are you saying the third cell should be red and 50% opacity?

Comment: I mean the third cell should be half filled with red and half white in the reference of the third cell's total width.

Comment: To do that you'd probably want to create a gradient background on that cell.

Comment: Thanks, it works! but there is a minor problem the color edge is not sharp it's gently blending into the other color on the right, don't know how to avoid that look.

Comment: You may want to post a new question about the gradient issue as it's not really part of this question.

Comment: Created separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42001167/partial-background-color-change-of-table-cell